# JavaFX: Application with multiple stage icons

Tags: javafx

I m trying to include multiple icons on a JavaFX application primary stage. However, only the first one appears every time but not the other two. the image URLs are right. Just that only a single icon appears. Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

```
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setMinHeight(1000);
primaryStage.setMinWidth(1000);
for(Type type:Type.values()) {
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(EnergyApp.class.getResource("icons/"+type.iconUrl()).toString(), 24, 24, true, true));
}
primaryStage.show();
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: A `Stage` can have multiple icons not so it can display all of them at once, but rather so it can choose the best sized image for the current display resolution. In other words, each icon should be the same image but with different dimensions (e.g. 16x16, 24x24, etc). I don't believe there's any way to do what you want with a decorated stage (i.e. with the OS' title bar). You could always make your stage undecorated and add your own custom title bar (difficult to make look native for each platform).

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer is:** This is not working. Perhaps, I couldn't know.

You just set a single image. For example:

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:icon.png"));
```